# How to make an app like Oldify in Java Using OpenCv Framework?

Tags: java, opencv, face-detection, face-recognition, imagefilter

How can we build an app that will detect a human face using camera and make it old. There are many apps like **Oldify** which can work on face aging but I really don't how they work.

I am little bit familiar with the face detection/recognition library which is OpenCv and have Java programming skills.

How can I build my app using these tools (Java/OpenCv)?

Comment: So, you're asking how to code the whole thing? That's way too broad, you need to try it yourself and come back with a detailed issue.

Comment: Hey @JamesZ, you are right but I just want to know that is it possible to make face aging effects using OpenCv if yes then is there learning resource so I can get help from there and start working on my project.